# How to change scenes in cocos2d while retaining state of the original scene

Tags: iphone, save, cocos2d-iphone, state

In my cocos2d project, I have two scenes.
I transition between the two using CCDirector's replaceScene.
Is it possible to save the state of the current scene so that when the scene is changed to a different scene, and then changed back to the original, all the objects and variables in the original are the same.

Thank you,

nonono

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `replaceScene`, you can use `pushScene:` and `popScene`. `pushScene:` puts the new scene onto a stack and displays it. When you are done that scene, call `popScene` to return to the previous scene on the stack.

```
[[Director sharedDirector] pushScene: newScene];
//...
[[Director sharedDirector] popScene];
```

Note that this does leave your previous scene in memory (as you asked), so it is [recommended](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices#director_flow_control) to use `replaceScene:` if you possibly can. If you do use `pushScene:` and `popScene`, it is best to keep your scene stack pretty small.

Comment: Thank you for your help however, when I try to pop the scene, after pushing it, the application ends, any suggestions?

Thank you